# Modifying the results of a Mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async.js

I'm working through the [MDN tutorial on ExpressJS with Mongoose](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs) and [Async](https://caolan.github.io/async/global.html) and at one point I am trying to query for all Books, and then map that to additional queries to find the number of BookInstances for each book. (For example I want to show a table of all the books in the database and then list how many copies we have)

```
// Display list of all books.
exports.book_list = function(req, res) {
  Book.find({}, 'title author')
    .exec(function(err, list){
      if (err) {return next(err);}

      async.map(list, function(book, next){
        BookInstance.countDocuments({book: book.id}, function(err, count){
          // Try and add the bookinstance count to the book object
          // use next(null, book);
        });
      }, function(err, modified_list){
        res.send(modified_list);
      });
    });
};
```

However, the following doesn't do anything:

```
book.count = count
next(null, book);
```

Nor does:

```
book.set("count", count");
next(null, book);
```

In both examples the item remained unmodified. However, the following returns what I'd expect:

```
var obj = {book: book, count: count};
next(null, obj);
```

Mongoose's docs describe that find() returns documents, but I can't figure out why they seem to be immutable, or what a Document actually is. Is there a way for me to just add a `count` property to the original returned object and not wrap it in another object?

Comment: Where and how are you calling next? your middleware should have `next` as it's third argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a property is not defined in the model, then mongoose doesn't directly allow you to add that property. However, you can use document._doc to change add new properties to the document.

Comment: I see, I was trying to treat the Document as a plain old javascript object but I guess since the Document enables updating the MongoDB instance, it restricts what I can do with it. If I modify ._doc, is the change actually reflected in the DB?

Comment: No, it only changes the document instance on the server side. It won't modify the actual data in the database.